# How it is possible to make one view controller to be viewed in Portrait view in iPhone

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiviewcontroller, uiinterfaceorientation

I am developing an app, which display number of books fetched from the server and it help the user to read through the book whenever he wants. In every book i am supposed to add simple games. Here, what i have done is, app to be start in a landscape view and it works fine. But now, i want only the game view controller (not the other VC ) should load in portrait view. I googled it , but can't find the real solution. Any help appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> By default, the UIViewController class displays views in portrait mode
>   only. To support additional orientations, you must override the
>   shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation: method and return YES for any
>   orientations your subclass supports.

So you just have to override your `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:` function in your view controller to view in portrait:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}
```

Comment: thanks for ur answer, i already used this method,but i can't turn the view to portrait

Comment: I just want to move particular view to portrait and the remaining should be in landscape view. Is any changes i have to done in (info.plist) of "Supported Orientation (iPad)", kindly give ur valuable solutions.